# ssh pubkey auth in subshell

Tags: bash, ssh, svn

Why is this not working:

```
svnout="$(/usr/bin/svn log -qr HEAD svn+ssh://user@ftp/repo)"
```

The problem seems to be the subshell. Why?

Public key auth is correctly set up and works fine without the subshell.

It's a passphraseless key BTW and ssh-agent is not involved.

Comment: Please explain how exactly that command is not working, what do you expect it to do and what does it do instead.

Comment: Well the actual problem seems to be to run it from nagios. Running it as the nagios user works fine, however when nagios itself runs it, it seems that that line is not working i.e. $?=1

Comment: Alright, what the hell. Even when running as nagios: svn: Can't check path '/root/.subversion': Permission denied ....

Comment: [solved] OK solved using /usr/bin/svn log --config-dir=/tmp/dummy -qr HEAD svn+ssh:/.....  see also these links [nagios check_svn](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Others/Check_Svn/details) [tigris bugs](http://websvn.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=32)

Comment: This question is considered to be unanswered by the site. I suggest you post your findings as answer and accept it once possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the --config-dir=/tmp/dummy option.

http://websvn.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=32